# Can't use WebJarAsset's "at" method (play 2.3.4)

Tags: jquery, scala, assets, playframework-2.3, webjars

I can't figure out why I cant use the WebJarAssets `at` method. 
My Configuration is as follows..

In my build.sbt:

```
...
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.11.1",
)
...
```

In my routes:

```
GET        /webjars/*file       controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Then in my main.scala.html I tried to add jquery like this..:

```
<script src="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But at this point the `at` method cant be accessed and I don't know why. 
I actually use play 2.3.4 and I just created this project, so there shouldn't be any conflicting libs.

Is there somebody able to help me with this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply james.

It suddenly worked without changing anything after I reimported my libs 2 or 3 times..